# How to apply the permeability value found from an experiment?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, experimental-physics, pressure-vessel, polyethylene

I have done a permeability experiment on LDPE in the presence of air using a 25mm circular specimen. At 30'C, the permeability was found to be 1.846 barrer.

[image]

Now I am trying to apply this permeability value to a calculation whereby I am trying to find what the change in pressure of a dunnage bag is (it is a bag that has the shape of a pillow) after 5 minutes. I have the following info of the dunnage bag:

- Volume of bag = 0.2064 m<sup>3</sup> (This was calculated using the Paper Bag Problem)
- Approximate area = 1.35 m<sup>2</sup> (this is just a quick approximate)
- Thickness of LDPE = 0.042 x 10<sup>-3</sup> m
- Time = 5 x 60 s = 300 s

Is it correct if I convert barrer to SI units in the following manner:

1 barrer = 7.5005 x 10<sup>-18</sup> m<sup>2</sup>s<sup>-1</sup>Pa<sup>-1</sup>

By using the following formula, I was hoping to calculate the change in pressure. However, my values don't make sense at all!

$$\text{Permeability} = \dfrac{\text{Volume}\cdot\text{thickness}}{\text{Area}\cdot\text{time}\cdot\text{Change in Pressure}}$$

Comment: I improved your formatting, including your equation at the end. However, given you didn't use parentheses to make what was dividing what explicit, I recommend that you take a look to see if I did it correctly. If not, feel free to [edit] your question as you see fit.